# JS isnt waiting at await

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await

the code bellow is just a short example from the full program but still with the same problem.
Im trying to save and load some config data, but the program isnt waiting at multiple spots. The main problem concerns the loading function. It returns an empty value before the actual file reading happend.

P.s.: There allways is a config.json file to read in the same directory regardless of saveConfig() function.

**main program:**

```
const config = require('./config');

async function start() {
    
    await config.saveConfig('test');
    var data = await config.loadConfig();

    console.log('Loaded data:' + data);
}

start();
```

**config.js:**

```
var fs = require('fs');

async function saveConfig(submittedConfigs){
    
    console.log("saveConfig: \tstart");
    
    fs.writeFile('config.json', JSON.stringify(submittedConfigs), function (err) {
        if (err) {
            return console.log(err);
        }
        console.log("saveConfig: \tThe file was saved!");
    }); 

    console.log("saveConfig: \tend")

}

async function loadConfig(){
    var configData
        
    fs.readFile('config.json', (err, fileData) => {
        if (err) {
            return Promise.reject(err);
        }
        
        configData = fileData;
        
        console.log("configData: \t" + configData);
        return Promise.resolve(configData);
    });
    
}

module.exports.saveConfig = saveConfig;
module.exports.loadConfig = loadConfig;
```

**console output:** *(the numbers in brackets indicating the desired order)*

> *(1)* saveConfig:     start
>
> *(3)* saveConfig:     end
>
> *(5)* Loaded data:    undefined
>
> *(2)* saveConfig:     The file was saved!
>
> *(4)* configData:     "test"

Comment: you are not awaiting writeFile nor readFile. you need to return a promise that resolves in the callback

Comment: You use the callback variations of  `writeFile` and `readFile`. Either you switch to the `async/await` variations or you have to create and manage a Promise by yourself.

Answer (score 2):

**Thumb rule:** `async` function should return `Promise`, so you can `await` for execution.
Please check code below `saveConfig, loadConfig` functions returning `Promise`

```
var fs = require('fs');

async function saveConfig(submittedConfigs){
    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
     console.log("saveConfig: \tstart");
    
      fs.writeFile('config.json', JSON.stringify(submittedConfigs), function (err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return reject(err);
        }
        console.log("saveConfig: \tThe file was saved!");
        return resolve();
      }); 
      console.log("saveConfig: \tend")
    });
}

async function loadConfig(){
    var configData
    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
       fs.readFile('config.json', (err, fileData) => {
        if (err) {
            return reject(err);
        }
        
        configData = fileData;
        
        console.log("configData: \t" + configData);
        return resolve(configData);
      });
    });
}

module.exports.saveConfig = saveConfig;
module.exports.loadConfig = loadConfig;
```